# HTML pattern not working for formatted phone number

Tags: javascript, html, regex

according to my regex test this should pass the pattern test... https://regex101.com/r/dT3vQC/1

However something is going wrong. Please help me understand this.

```js
function formatPhone(obj) {
  var numbers = obj.value.replace(/\D/g, ''),
    char = {
      0: '(',
      3: ') ',
      6: ' - '
    };
  obj.value = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    obj.value += (char[i] || '') + numbers[i];
  }
  console.log(obj.value)
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input required type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="(xxx) xxx - xxxx" onblur="formatPhone(this);" onkeypress="formatPhone(this);" pattern="\([0-9]{3}\)\s[0-9]{3}\s-\s[0-9]{4}" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('please enter 10 digit number')">
  <button>check</button>
</form>
```

Comment: also tried ` pattern="\D*(\d\D*){10}"` and it works, but it has a bug. If i submit with a bad value it fails the test every time after the first failed attempt. In chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Basically I was confused about the api for `setCustomValidity` if you set it to an empty string that means it isn't going to fire. If that value is set it will fire on every submit. Here is a working example.

```js
function formatPhone(phoneInput) {
            var numbers = phoneInput.value.replace(/\D/g, ''),
                char = { 0: '(', 3: ') ', 6: ' - ' };
            phoneInput.value = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
                phoneInput.value += (char[i] || '') + numbers[i];
            }

        }

        function checkPhone(phoneInput) {
            var formatted = phoneInput.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
            if (formatted.length !== 10) {
                phoneInput.setCustomValidity('please enter 10 digit number')
            } else {
                phoneInput.setCustomValidity(""); // be sure to leave this empty! 
            }
        }
```

```html
<form>
<input required type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="(xxx) xxx - xxxx"
                    oninput="checkPhone(this);" onblur="formatPhone(this);" onkeypress="formatPhone(this);">
<button>check</button>
</form>
```